# How to convert time 01:15:19.780-06:00 to 13:15

Tags: android

I have little bit problem how to convert time,

```
01:15:19.780-06:00 to 13:15.
```

please answer me.

Comment: Frankly I didn't get the question.

Comment: I think you should explain what you mean by "Cache", "Comes Home screen" and "current screen Position"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `onBackPressed()` in your Activity. If you leave the method body empty, you'll stay on the current screen.

Comment: ok thanks bro,when i remove code super.onBackPressed(); then no any action

Comment: please like this question because i can not able to like your answer due to less point. please

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, simply mark it as accepted, that's the way to define an answer as "problem-solving", and you don't need reputation to do this.